# Pyinstaller : How to do specific module import?

Tags: python, module, pyinstaller, python-venv, pyrebase

I have created an app with PyCharm as IDE, my app works perfectly.

Then I create an exe.

Then I get an error `No module named 'pyrebase'` when I launch the exe.

I think pyinstaller is using my PC libraries right ?

So I would like to precise "use pyrebase from my PyCharm's project venv and not from my PC which seems to not have it". (I have a wheel installation problematic)

Is it possible ?

Comment: Are you using pyinstaller from anywhere outside your venv/IDE? If so, don't. Use it inside pycharm and it should have the same environment (and packages) that you are using

Comment: My hero ! That's just so simple and that worked perfectly ! <3